# Akka java.lang.AssertionError: timeout (3 seconds) during expectMessage while waiting

Tags: java, timeout, akka-cluster

I am running a multi-jvm:test on my Amazon linux ec2 instance of 4vcpu and 16gb capacity(t2.xlarge). I am running 2 nodes. Whenever I run the sbt multi-jvm:test command,

```
java.lang.AssertionError: timeout (3 seconds) during expectMessage while waiting for com.psing069.akka.sample.BankAccount$Account@30331109
```

I have tried everything. I pointer is highly appreciated. Thank you.

My test:

```
"handle updates directly after start" in within(60.seconds) {
            runOn(node2) {
                bankAccount ! new BankAccount.Deposit(200)
                bankAccount ! new BankAccount.Withdraw(100)
            }
            enterBarrier("updates-done")

            awaitAssert {
                val probe = TestProbe[Account]()
                bankAccount ! new BankAccount.GetBalance(probe.ref)
                // val state = probe.expectMessageType[Account](60.seconds)
                // state.balance should be (100)
                probe.expectMessage(new Account(100))

            }

            enterBarrier("after-2")
        }
```

and my actor is:

```
public static class Account {
        //String account_number;
        int balance;
        public Account(int balance){
            this.balance = balance;
            //this.account_number = account_number;
        }
    }

private static class InternalGetResponse implements Command {
        public final GetResponse<PNCounter> rsp;
        public final ActorRef<Account> replyTo;

        private InternalGetResponse(GetResponse<PNCounter> rsp, ActorRef<Account> replyTo) {
          this.rsp = rsp;
          this.replyTo = replyTo;
        }
    }

private Behavior<Command> onGetBalance(GetBalance command) {
        replicator.askGet(
            askReplyTo -> new Get<>(dataKey, readMajority, askReplyTo),
            rsp -> new InternalGetResponse(rsp, command.replyTo)
        );
        return Behaviors.same();
    }

private Behavior<Command> onInternalGetResponse(InternalGetResponse msg) {
        if (msg.rsp instanceof GetSuccess) {
            PNCounter data = ((GetSuccess<PNCounter>) msg.rsp).get(dataKey);
            msg.replyTo.tell(new Account(data.getValue().intValue()));
        } else if (msg.rsp instanceof NotFound) {
            msg.replyTo.tell(new Account(0));
        } else if (msg.rsp instanceof GetFailure) {
          // ReadMajority failure, try again with local read
            replicator.askGet(
                askReplyTo -> new Get<>(dataKey, Replicator.readLocal(), askReplyTo),
                rsp -> new InternalGetResponse(rsp, msg.replyTo)
            );
        }
        return Behaviors.same();
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Java, but the solution is the same: you need to configure the `leeway` timeout in the configuration

```
akka{
    loggers =  [akka.testkit.TestEventListener]
    log-level = DEBUG
    test{
        filter-leeway = 10 seconds
        default-timeout = 12 seconds
    }
}
```

Also you have to be sure to load the config inside your CI environment. For example when you create the ActorSystem load the correct config

```java
 Config config = ConfigFactory.load("application-test");
 ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create(testSystemName, config);
```